# AngularJS Print Yes or No based on boolean value

Tags: angularjs

I'm getting Bool value from database to angularJs

```
<td>
    {{patient.Alcoholic}}
</td>
```

instead of false or ture i need to print YES or NO

```
<td>
    {{patient.Alcoholic // can i have if-else condition over here ??}}
</td>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
<td>
 {{true == patient.Alcoholic ? 'Yes' : 'No' }}
</td>
```

This should work!

Comment: just use `{{patient.Alcoholic ? 'Yes' : 'No' }}`

Answer (score 11):

use **ng-if directive**

```
 <td ng-if="patient.Alcoholic">Yes</td>
 <td ng-if="!patient.Alcoholic">NO</td>
```

Comment: Yours is a more appropriate answer.

Comment: Both working, one is ternary another is pure AngularJs, thanks :)

Comment: @Simply - Try to use angular way, Its my suggestion Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Simply do

```
<td>
 {{ patient.Alcoholic ? 'Yes' : 'No' }}
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to not put JS operations in your template, as it will:

- Make your template dirty (*imho*).
- Strain the application (*very minor argument*), as the evaluation is being run on each `$digest` cycle.

If you are fine with modifying the original `bool` of the patient:

```
$scope.patient.Alcoholic = !!$scope.patient.Alcoholic ? 'Yes' : 'No';
```

If not, I would add another property onto `patient`:

```
$scope.patient.isAlcoholic = !!$scope.patient.Alcoholic ? 'Yes' : 'No';
```

And then in your view (dependent on the solution you've chosen of the two above):

```
{{ patient.Alcoholic }}
<!-- or -->
{{ patient.isAlcoholic }}
```

---

That's my two cents on keeping your template *clean*.

Comment: Feel free to update the accepted answer and/or up it, if you found the given answer useful.